# Selenium - Visual Studios- C# - All (chrome, firefox, and internet explorer) webdrivers unable to start driver service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to set up Selenium for testing and none of my webdrivers seem to work.  I have tried moving them around in the project folder and the only way I can get Visual Studios to locate them is with a @"path" statement.

The real problem is... Once Visual Studio locates the webdriver, the operation times out and I get the following exception:

*An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
Additional information:  Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:(random port number that changes every time)*

I have tried restarting my computer and having the system administrator check the firewall and malware blocker logs, but neither seems to have helped (or they don't know the correct thing to look for).

I figure this is something super simple and I'm just missing it... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a copy of my code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

namespace SeleniumWork
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\blahblahpathstring");

                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");

                IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

                query.SendKeys("Cheese");

                query.Submit();

                var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                wait.Until(d => d.Title.StartsWith("cheese", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

                Console.WriteLine("Page title is: " + driver.Title);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a copy of the debug output I receive:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
```

Comment: I think the problem is because it's not finding your webdrivers. Did you right click on them, and set as "Copy Always = TRUE"? With that, your drivers will be at the same level as your other assemblies.

Comment: Are you referring to the Copy to Output Directory property?  I just marked that to Copy Always and cannot start the driver service error.   The properties on the webdrivers are... Build Action: Content,    Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always,  Custom Tool:  (blank),  Custom Tool Namespace: (blank), File Name: IEDriverServer.exe/GeckoDriver.exe/ChromeDriver.exe

Comment: Copy to Output directory. Sorry, my bad...

Comment: thanks for reporting this issue, since this exception caused giving errors for various ports. One good thing to verify is any anti-virus services running on you machine. The solution worked for me was to 'disable' all antivirus "client" services running on my machine. In my case I compared firewall settings and anti virus services running on my colleagues machine where solution was already successfully built, thanks for reporting this issue again

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem on my work machine, but not on my personal machine. The only difference I could attribute between the two was that I was using VS 2015 at home and VS 2017 at work.

What fixed it was I used the NuGet Package Manager for the project and downloaded the Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver by jbaranda, which uses the new *marionette* based web driver rather than *gecko* driver.

With this installed I was able to get a firefox browser up and running without any extra configuration or options:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Url = "www.google.com";
```

Whereas before it would throw the 'Cannot start the driver service...' exception you mentioned. There are NuGet packages for other browsers which I suggest for the particular one you're using, but the only one I didn't have that issue with was IE. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and had had no idea how to fix it. In the end I found out that the Firewall blocked the traffic to loopback. The firewall installed on the machine is McAffe.

All I did was stopping the service which manages traffic scan.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been hitting this consistently on IEDriverServer and rarely on FireFox.

Fixed it twice when it happened on FireFox - first time I updated the gecko driver, second time I restarted my PC. Something in the environment's going on, maybe the driver does not fully quit sometimes, so new instantiations are being blocked?

Answer (score 0):

I think mostly beginners face this problem when they are running Selenium with C# for the first time.

As i also faced this situation. As highlighted in one of the answer and let me show with images

**You have installed Selenium.webDriver but you have not installed Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver**

**Step 1 :-** Go to Nugget Manager

[image]

**Step 2 :-** Select Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver and install it

[image]

Now run the program once again and that problem will go away.