# Why can Selenium GECKO driver for Firefox 48 not start the server?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

We are running Selenium 2.5.3 in a .Net Automation Testing Project setup as a NUnit Test project.

Everything worked fine with Firefox 47. But with Firefox 48 it stopped working.
I pulled down the Gecko.exe (version 9) from github.
I can almost get it running but not quite.

I was getting these errors:
Additional information: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:53628/session timed out after 30 seconds.

Additional information: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:55924/session timed out after 30 seconds.

It seems that the default is to use random ports.
So I manually set it to Port 7500, opened the port in Windows Firewall, and now I got this:
Additional information: Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:7500/

Here is my Code in the WebDriverFactory:

```
case WebDriverType.Firefox:
                Log.Info("Starting Firefox ...");

                //string driverPath =
                //    $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)}\\wires.exe";

                string driverPath =
                    @"C:\Development2\iRePORT\src\test\csharp\Nete.Ireport.EndToEndTests\bin\Debug\geckodriver.exe";

                FirefoxDriverService driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                driverService.FirefoxBinaryPath = driverPath;
                driverService.Port = 7500;

                FirefoxOptions ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
                ffOptions.IsMarionette = true;
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService, ffOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

                // driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxOptions());

                Log.Info("Started");
                break;
```

I have spent a lot of time on this and I feel like I am very close.
Does anyone know what piece I am missing?

---

I read something now that makes me think this line;

```
driverService.FirefoxBinaryPath = driverPath;
```

points to what vesion of Firefox install to use.
I have now put the driverpath and executable name in the driverService Constructor like this:

```
case WebDriverType.Firefox:
                Log.Info("Starting Firefox ...");

                //string driverPath =
                //    $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)}\\wires.exe";

                string driverPath =
                    @"C:\Development2\iRePORT\src\test\csharp\Nete.Ireport.EndToEndTests\bin\Debug";
                string driverExecutableName = "geckodriver.exe";

                FirefoxDriverService driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverPath, driverExecutableName);
                // Don't do this!!! This is the executable to the Firefox Version executable.
                //driverService.FirefoxBinaryPath = driverPath;
                driverService.Port = 7500;

                FirefoxOptions ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
                ffOptions.IsMarionette = true;
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService, ffOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

                // driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxOptions());

                Log.Info("Started");
                break;
```

So now I am back to getting this error:
Additional information: Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:7500/

---

Also if I have:
driverService.Port = 7200;
It says "entity not found".  I believe it means it cannot find Gecko.exe.
If I have:
driverService.Port = 7500;
It says:
Additional information: Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:7500/

Comment: Posted an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005512/selenium-visual-studios-c-sharp-all-chrome-firefox-and-internet-explorer/43372184#43372184
that might be relevant to this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try Selenium 3.0.0. I've also had this problem but i finally manage all things to run switching from 2.53.1 to 3.0.0