# Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' in WebDriver.dll

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium using C#. Whenever I try to run simple code i get :

```
Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' in WebDriver.dll
```

everytime.

Note: I am using Win 10, Visual studio enterprise edition 2015 , Selenium 3x and Chrome latest version.
Below is the Code. Thanks in Advance

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Selenium1
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create the reference
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            IWebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.Id("gs_htif0"));
            ele.SendKeys("Execute Automation");
        }
    }
}
```

Getting Following Exception:

[image: Refer attached image]
[image: Reference Screenshot]

Getting following Exception Everytime, No luck.. I have tried everything.
[image]

Nuget Packages:
[image]

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Update the question with error stack trace

Comment: Did you add references properly? expand and show your references and webdriver version.

Comment: Yes I have installed all the reference: Refer screenshot:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for inconvience, there was problem related to compatibility between my Browser and Driver which I was using. With compatible driver and browser its works fine. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

as your image shows you have installed references correctly,
but still it seems configurational problems with references,
you need to declare namespaces then see if it gets errors or not,

```
using OpenQA.Selenium; 
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome; // or more specific its ok you get no error till here
```

I hope options will be the issue for you,
then you also need some configurational options to provide in the constuctor,

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", "YOUR_DownloadPath");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");                        
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
chromeOptions.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
```

then, use

```
try{
IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
}catch(Exception e){Console.writeLine(e);}
```

you need to put your code in try catch block,
So, you can get full error exception trace and please provide that to us.
have you got any success to open chrome browser ?
ok chrome browser can open,
Refere this, might be duplicate question,
your code uses the new marionette based web driver rather than gecko driver.

[Selenium - Visual Studios- C# - All (chrome, firefox, and internet explorer) webdrivers unable to start driver service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005512/selenium-visual-studios-c-sharp-all-chrome-firefox-and-internet-explorer)

try to use Nuget package manager and download assembly references again

Comment: Yes Chrome browser is opened but nothing happened after browser is opened.

Comment: Ok let me try once more

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample test class and how I create the driver

```
driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
```

And from my NuGet packages I am using Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver 2.41.0, Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver and Selenium.WebDriver 3.14,Selenium.Support 3.14

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace MyTest.UITest
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Create the reference
        IWebDriver driver =new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        IWebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.Id("gs_htif0"));
        ele.SendKeys("Execute Automation");
    }
}
```

}

Since, you don beleve me ;)

[image]

Comment: Is there any compatiblity issue??

Comment: Have you add all packages from NuGet as I did ?

Comment: Yes I did. You can refer screenshot

Comment: Yes I have fully Copy/paste. This is what I get, that's why I am scratching my head what I am missing. I am using Win 10 and Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3. Just very begenning and I am stuck in this only.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered with the same problem and was not able to proceed. In the error list, I had a couple of errors where it tries to copy the chrome driver file but could not access it as some other process was using it. I believe it was not disposed properly in the previous run, which had opened a couple of console sessions and hadn't closed, closing those just fixed this issue. Thanks.