# Sendkeys not working , but object found , c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath, sendkeys

I am developing an application in c#.
And i need to fill out some register forms on web pages.

Lets take Url: https://registrierung.gmx.net as example

So i am using `FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@data-test='first-name-input']"));`

to find the element (in this case First name input).

like `var result = PJSDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@data-test='first-name-input']"));`

So now using `result.Click();` is Working and also touching the field.
(It gets red ....)

SO NOW COMES THE PROBLEM

When i try to use `result.SendKeys("fistname");`
it throws an error.

("OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException" in WebDriver.dll)(not a real info..)

the code would be like:

`Console.WriteLine("Using:"+data.name);
result = PJSDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@data-test='first-name-input']"));
result.Click();
//Thread.Sleep(1000); 
//result.sendkeys("Last-name");`

(Even when clicking on it first and then wait and then sendkeys, also not working)

My Question is :

How to get Sendkeys working to send keys to the object ?

1. Do i need to change xpath ? (but click works?) (Iframe problem ?)
2. Is there any workaround ? (javascript executor also not working)
3. Is there any way to get more output from the SeleniumDriver?

I am using VisualStudio at the moment.
Would be real nice to get some help here.

ERROR FROM VisualStudio : (yes there is no more output)

```
Ausnahme ausgelöst: "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException" in WebDriver.dll
```

Thanks.

Comment: *not a real info* is that literally what it says? I would be expecting something like "Unexpected error. TypeError". You should include the exact error as it may help answer your question.

Comment: You still haven't shown what error you get from whatever code you are using. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help

Comment: Hey There is no more output then: Ausnahme ausgelöst: "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException" in WebDriver.dll

Comment: It may be worth checking the version of WebDrider is compatible with the browser version you are using. There is a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732830/exception-thrown-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-in-webdriver-dll) which mentioned it resolved an issue

Comment: That was a helpful Comment, thanks :-) but SendKeys  is working on another webppage without problems.